# What's a good strategy for key names on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, hash

I'm looking to store a large collection of user-submitted images onto S3. What's a good strategy for key names? I was thinking something like:

```
thumb-150-150-{md5hash}.jpg
```

Is this a good/bad idea? Should security be a concern? Maybe I should be salting these images with some kind of random UUID hash?

```
thumb-150-150-{md5hash}-{uniqueid}.jpg
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I definitely would not use: thumb-150-150-{md5hash}.jpg because suppose two users upload the exact same image.  If you do decide to go with that method to reduce disk space, you will need to come up with some logic to make sure one users deletion doesn't affect another user -- but that's a whole different discussion.

If you really want to make sure that you do not have any filename collisions, you could md5 the timestamp and append it to the filename as the uniqueid.

Comment: This was really helpful. Didn't think about one user deleting another user's photo if there's no timestamp. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hash should be at the start of the filename to randomize partitions. timestamp may not be unique.